# ASP.NET MVC4 Rendering Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am currently doing this tutorial http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/.

The problem with mine is that it does not render the page but redirects me to a new Action with new form. What do I miss and how to fix it? Here is the code.

Model:

```
namespace MvcPartialsExample.Models
{
    public class Gift
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var initialData = new[] {
            new Gift { Name = "Tall Hat", Price = 39.95 },
            new Gift { Name = "Long Cloak", Price = 120.00 },
        };
        return View(initialData);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Gift g)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult BlankEditorRow()
    {
        return View("GiftEditorRow" , new Gift());
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcPartialsExample.Models.Gift>

<script src="~/Scripts/listEditor.js"></script>

@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div class="editorRows">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow", item);
        }
    </div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add Gift", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

GiftEditorRow.cshtml

```
@model MvcPartialsExample.Models.Gift

<div ="editorRow">
   @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("gifts")) {
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
       <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
   }
</div>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("a.deleteRow").live("click", function () {
        $(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need `GiftEditorRow.ascx` not  `GiftEditorRow.cshtml`

Comment: Not related, but your POST method needs to be `IEnumerable<Gift> g` and it needs to be `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem())` (no prefix) and `.live` has been depreciated. Is your script being hit?, do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: What does BeginCollectionItem do? Can't see it on the link

Comment: I dont post anything so it doesnt matter what I have inside my POST method for now.So far no errors in console but I am not really sure if javascript its being hit. I've put another JS and its not working as well `$("#addItem").click(function () {
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script for `$("#addItem").click(function () {` is in the `Scripts/listEditor.js` file, you need to move it to the bottom of the page or wrap the script in `$(document).ready()`. Currently its at the top of the page and the element with `id="addItem"` does not even exist yet. The script will never be called and the links just performs a normal redirect.

It would be better to make the element a `<button type="button">` (and style it as a link if that's what you want it to look like).

Side notes

1. Your POST method needs to be `public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Gift> g)` (your posting back a collection)
2. The helper needs to be `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem(""))` (not `BeginCollectionItem("gifts")` which would add the prefix "gifts" to
   the controls, but your model does not have a property named `gifts`)
3. `.live` has been depreciated - use `.on` instead, but in any case it
   needs to be `$('#editorRows').on('click', '.deleteRow', function()
   {...`

Comment: `Html.BeginCollectionItem()` by itself requires a collection name string so it doesnt let me to have it empty. Even with wrapping the JS with `$(document).ready()` or having it inside the webpage doesnt work.

Comment: Put a break point in the script or add a `console.log('got here')` to check if you are actually hitting the script.

Comment: Also you can use `Html.BeginCollectionItem("")` (or `string.Empty`). Check the html your generating for the existing items. It needs to be `[xxx].Name` (not `gifts[xxx].Name` in order to bind to your collection on post back (where `xxx` is a `guid`)

Comment: Best to also specify `dataType: 'html',` in the ajax call (although that's unlikely to be the issue)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow", Model);
```

Instead of

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow", item);
}
```

On your `GiftEditorRow.cshtml` page loop through all items in model.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `@Html.ActionLink("Add Gift", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })` element in your emited html. This is probably creating an `<a href="/BlankEditor">Add Gift</a>` element which will cause a redirect.

Try creating a button element instead `<button type="button" id="addItem" />`

Your js will then create the onClick event